# Who is legally responsible for tiedown ropes?

Tags: faa-regulations, airport, airport-operations

When an airport has tie downs listed on their official FAA record, who is responsible for the ropes/chains. Is there any federal regulation or legal precedent for this or is it a case-by-case determination based on the FBO policy?

Comment: Are you saying the Chart Supplement says there are tiedowns but in reality there aren't, and you're asking if that's the FAA's responsibility or the FBO's responsibility? Or are you asking if FBOs are required to provide tiedowns? Or something else? It would be great if you could explain a little more about exactly what you want to know.

Comment: Alternately, are you asking who is liable if they’re provided but fail, and your plane gets damaged as a result?

Comment: This reads like a frustrated pilot who forgot to bring his own straps.  Trust me, we don’t want the FAA inspecting and legally micromanaging at this level.  10 dollar auto part store straps will become 100 dollar Aerospace grade tie downs.

Comment: That could be read as : To PROVIDE tie downs | To MAINTAIN tiedowns | To ensure tiedowns are utilised and recovered correctly  | ???

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I read this as "there is a place to park your plane for a while and tie it down if you are so inclined."  I do not expect the airport to provide the chains or ropes.  Some will, but small town or village airports are barely maintained and nobody is thinking about how to make life better for transient airplane owners.  If you intend to park and leave the plane for any length of time you should be carrying your own means of physically securing the airplane to the ground.

It's the pilot's responsibility to ensure the plane is safe.